# Google has disabled use of Maps API for this application

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I got this error on my site

`Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html.`

I try clear browser data, cache etc. but no luck. This is my code.

`<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>`

and i change it to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXX&sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>`

But stil no luck. this site is working for 3 yrs and suddenly i got this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do what was suggested -- check the terms of agreement and contact Google to get the capability reinstated.  You may have exceeded the number of accesses per second (for example), or run afoul of one of the other restrictions.

Check your Google account screen for API usage.

Comment: Do you know how do i contact google? Is there an email support or chat for google map api user? I think the problem is my domain is block by google because when i change my domain example.com to example.biz its work fine.

Comment: Do you have a Google API account? a Google Apps account?